# Getting error when trying to select from databese

Tags: discord.js, mysql2

So, Im trying to make economy for each guild aka server but the code isnt working even when I looked on mysql2 npm I typed it all correctly but I cant set 2 search parameters as like Guild ID and User ID which I would like to use.

My code:

```
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM ecn WHERE gid = "${message.guild.id}" AND id = ${message.author.id}`, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let sql;
    if(rows.length < 1){
      slq = `INSERT INTO ecn (gid, id, cash) VALUES ('${message.guild.id}', '${message.author.id}', ${generateCash()})`
      con.query(sql);
    } else {
      let gid = rows[0].gid;
      let cash = rows[0].cash;
      sql = `UPDATE ecn SET cash = ${cash + generateCash()} WHERE gid = '${message.guild.id}' AND id = ${message.author.id}`;
      con.query(sql);
      return;
    }
  })
```

And this is on mysql npm page:

```
connection.query(
  'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = "Page" AND `age` > 45',
  function(err, results, fields) {
    console.log(results); // results contains rows returned by server
    console.log(fields); // fields contains extra meta data about results, if available
  }
);
```

I get error response:

```
C:\Users\----------\Desktop\hb\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:494
    if (sql.constructor === Commands.Query) {
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
    at Connection.query (C:\Users\----------\Desktop\hb\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:494:13)
    at Query.onResult (C:\Users\----------\Desktop\hb\index.js:58:11)
    at C:\Users\----------\Desktop\hb\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\query.js:70:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

Comment: fix it variable -> slq

Comment: ah why am I so dumb some times... like for real. I can over see this small bugs how.